# Managing state in object graph spawned by Batchable

Tags: apex, batch

##### Prelude

I understand the following regarding batch Apex:

| State | Variable Values |
| --- | --- |
| stateful | static are reset for each batch `execute()` run |
|  | instance (non-static) are maintained across all batch `execute()` runs |
| non-stateful | static are reset for each batch `execute()` run |
|  | instance (non-static) are reset for each batch `execute()` run |

As I understand it, each batch `execute()` run is considered a separate transaction.

##### Background

In an inherited org, I just ran across a non-stateful batch class, which within the `execute()` method references a `static` variable in a *separate* non-`Batchable` class.

##### Simplified Example

**Separate Class**

```java
public class SeparateClass {
    public static Set<Id> staticSetIds = new Set<Id>();
}
```

**Batch Class**

```java
public class NonStatefulBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // build query
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
        // Work
        for (Account acc : scope) {
            if (!SeparateClass.staticSetIds.contains(acc.Id) {
            // More work
            SeparateClass.staticSetIds.add(acc.Id);
        }
        // Even more work
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug('Finished');
    }
}
```

##### Comments

This separate class' `static` variable is also used in other contexts, such as triggers, where -- if I understand correctly -- it will do what I think they want it to do as all "batches" of a trigger run are considered the same transaction: This variable will maintain value for the full run of the trigger.

I *think* the original code writer was expecting/hoping that the same thing would happen in this batch class.

#### Questions

1. Is my assumption that each batch `execute()` run is a separate transaction, thus this separate class' `static` variable value will **not** be maintained for the full run of the batches?
2. Would it act differently if this batch class were `Stateful`?

---

### UPDATE 1

*Minutes after posting the original question*

I posted this too soon, maybe. After further analysis I see that the batch updates Accounts, and the `SeparateClass.staticSetIds` is referenced in the `before update` of the Account trigger handler.  I haven't looked at the `1`s and `0`s yet, but maybe that is why it is used in this batch.

Comment: 1.Yes. 2. No - as long as `SeparateClass` is not referenced by the object graph tied to any instance variable. One possible solution: based on the state of your (stateful) `Batchable`. you construct the `SeparateClass` and initialize it with whatever state it needs. Another solution: have the state in your `Batchable` include `SeparateClass` (via an instance variable) and update it as needed throughout the runs. While this solution might appear cleaner, serialization issues could bite.

Comment: Where a static is declared has (almost) zero bearing on its lifecycle. They are always scoped to a transaction, being initialized on first reference within the transaction (this being the only thing it influences - no reference in the txn, then never set). Perhaps they use it to influence processing where this static is used elsewhere. If, say, this batch also performs DML on Account and the static is used somewhere in the Account trigger handling then that trigger handling would be influenced by this static since the DML would be part of the same transaction as the batch `execute`.